# Prevent divs aligned from overlapping

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to start by saying the title has yielded some similar questions, but I've tried the solutions such as `z-index`, `display: inline-block`, and `overflow:hidden`, and some other select fixes that was suggested. None of those has fixed my issue.

When I resize my browser with the following code the divs will overlap each.

My aspx:

```
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="contentOne">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item One"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTwo">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Two"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentThree">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Three"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#contentOne {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 80%;
    min-width: 200px;
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
#contentTwo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
#contentThree {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
#contentContainer {
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[**Here's a fiddle to save time**](https://jsfiddle.net/2we0yqx5/)

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: try using css flexbox for aligning your content. it is very flexible. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ... this guide will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is not a method for laying out things relative to one another. Flexbox or Grid are CSS methods for this.

## Flexbox Method

```css
#contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

#contentOne,
#contentTwo,
#contentThree {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="contentOne">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item One"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTwo">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Two"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentThree">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Three"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Grid Method

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) has a good guide to getting started with [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```css
#contentContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

#contentOne,
#contentTwo,
#contentThree {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="contentOne">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item One"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemOne" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTwo">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Two"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemTwo" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="contentThree">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Three"></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="txt_itemThree" runat="server" Text="Sample Item Description"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This got the result I was looking for. Any tips on expanding on my css knowledge (good sites for review)? It's been awhile since I've touched css, hence the poor coding of it.

Comment: The two I linked to above ([Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/)) are good places to get started, I visit these almost daily. Reading through [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/book/) or [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) will help with good approaches to writing modular CSS, or rather CSS with low-specificity that embraces the cascade. CSS layout has gotten a lot better and more intuitive since flexbox and grid came along – best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to the method you are trying to use. It may not have the same effect you are looking for but it is mobile responsive and has better syntax.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* STRUCTURE */

.wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .columns .column {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    flex-basis: 40%;
    &:nth-last-child(2) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    &:last-child {
      flex-basis: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .columns .column {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="columns">

    <div class="column">
      <h2>1st Content Area</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ratione architecto necessitatibus cum praesentium dolor totam voluptatibus recusandae?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>2nd Content Area</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ratione architecto necessitatibus cum praesentium dolor totam voluptatibus recusandae? Illo quod nemo ratione itaque dolores laudantium error vero laborum blanditiis nostrum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <h2>3rd Content Area</h2>
      <p>Illo quod nemo ratione itaque dolores laudantium error vero laborum blanditiis nostrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ratione architecto cum praesentium voluptatibus recusandae?</p>
    </div>

  </section>
```